# 4-Channel 16-Bit ADC for Raspberry Pi (ADS1115) - Can I connect two analog sensors?

Tags: raspberry-pi, sensors

I have a RP4 and thinking about buying EC and PH sensors from `Grove`. I've learned that RP4 doesn't have an analog input so I'm thinking about connecting it through `ADS1115` from `Grove`.
I'm not sure about the connections, so I would like to know if for two sensor will need two ADS1115, or can I use one for both sensors in a same time?
Also if I need two, it is possible to connect one on the top of the next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Seedstudio [doc](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-16-bit-ADC-ADS1115/) for the part says it has 4 channels so you should be able to connect up to 4 analogue sensors to each ADS1115 device.

The ADS1115 devices can also be configured with 4 different i2c addresses which means you can connect up to 4 of them to a single i2c bus, which would mean up to 16 analogue sensors in total to a Pi (using the default single i2c bus).